# Автозаполнение синтаксиса языка Java в Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Начал работу в новой для себя среде Netbeans, в которой к моему сожалению отсутствовала функция автозаполнения синтаксиса (которая имела место быть например в Visual Studio). Мб кто нибудь подскажет конкретные подключаемые шаблоны для решения сей проблемы?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Intellij IDEA, пристально посмотрите..

Answer (score 0):

Для настройки автозавершения кода выберите "Сервис" > "Параметры" > "Редактор" > "Автозавершение кода".